# How to retrieve the [Date] Array?

Tags: parse-platform

One of my object's column has one array with Dates object.

How to parse back during my object's retrieving?
I have tried:
passional.xDates = parsePassional[PassionalXlancing.Dates] as? [Date]

But it seems not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found parse seems not allow us to cast the array to [Date], but we can cast to [String] then translate by yourself. My demo solution below:

```
if let dates = parsePassional[PassionalXlancing.Dates] as? [String] {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        var resultDates = [Date]()
        for dateString in dates {
            let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
            resultDates.append(dateObj!)
        }
        passional.xDates = resultDates
    }
```